# `validators` keyword argument not working when `many` is True?

Tags: django, django-rest-framework

```
def validate_number_of_product(products):
    if len(products) > 1:
        # this may be temporary
        raise ValidationError(_('Too many products.'))


class OrderAddSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    products = serializers.PrimaryKeyRelatedField(
        queryset=Product.objects.filter(sold=False),
        write_only=True,
        validators=[validate_number_of_product],
        many=True, allow_empty=False,
    )

    # ...
```

I'm using `PrimaryKeyRelatedField` with `many=True`, and also need to validate the field (independently). But it seems that `validate_number_of_product` is not called when calling `OrderAddSerializer.is_valid()`. Is this a limitation of DRF or is because I'm using it incorrectly?

Answer (score 2):

`many=True` has a different behavior from what you assumed.
It creates a `ListSerializer` behind the scene to handle the list part and delegates each instance to the "initial" serializer.

You'll need to ensure that validators are given to the `ListSerializer` instead of the `OrderAddSerializer`.

The [documentation](http://www.django-rest-framework.org/api-guide/serializers/#customizing-listserializer-initialization) explains how you can customize the `ListSerializer` initialization. As you can see in [the source](https://github.com/encode/django-rest-framework/blob/master/rest_framework/serializers.py#L129), validators are filtered out of init through [`LIST_SERIALIZER_KWARGS`](https://github.com/encode/django-rest-framework/blob/master/rest_framework/serializers.py#L75).

Comment: This is helpful. Thanks!